# Vaadin Tree from list of entities

Tags: vaadin

I'm quite new in Vaadin and have faced next issue. I'm trying to represent my list of entities using Tree with grouping by some properties. Everything was fine till the first level of items. What I've done:

```
MyEntity myEntity1 = new MyEntity(1l, "prop1", "sub_prop0")
MyEntity myEntity2 = new MyEntity(2l, "prop1", "sub_prop1")
MyEntity myEntity3 = new MyEntity(3l, "prop2", "sub_prop2")

BeanContainer<Long, MyEntity > entityContainer = new BeanContainer<>(MyEntity .class);
marketContainer.setBeanIdProperty("prop"); // prop is property name for the second value in constructor
entityContainer.addBean(myEntity1);
entityContainer.addBean(myEntity2);
entityContainer.addBean(myEntity3)

Tree markets = new Tree("Markets");
markets.setContainerDataSource(entityContainer);
```

as a result I've got the Tree with 2 items: prop1 and prop2 but nothing else. Actually the only I need additional is to have sup-elements with values form another property as a child items.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation and example found [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-tree.html).

In short:

Set the parent of the child object

```
// Set it to be a child.
tree.setParent(l2, l1);
```

If no children are allowed, tell it so

```
/* Make the moons look like leaves. */
tree.setChildrenAllowed(l2, false);
```

If you wish to define the Hierachie in the Container, then use one of the Containers implementing the [HierarchicalContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/HierarchicalContainer.html).
There you also use the `setParent(...)` method to specify relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it mean that containerDataSource, in my case it is BeanContainer, and relationships in tree have to be configured in different way? I mean that have I to provide my datasource and after iterate over it and configure parent/child relationships?

Comment: If you wish to define it on container level, then you need to use a `HierarchicalContainer`as documented here https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/HierarchicalContainer.html. There you also have to define the setParent(....) for the children (as you could in the Tree component)

Comment: Thanks again, so looks like that to build a Tree with parents and children the only HierarchicalContainer is the suitable datasource but not BeanContainer, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, or more exact, any Container implementing the `Container.Hierarchical`interface. https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Container.Hierarchical.html. Probably you could use the `ContainerHierarchicalWrapper` arround your BeanContainer for this. https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/ContainerHierarchicalWrapper.html